# Trouble with integration

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am having trouble calculating this integral.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by \begin{equation}
   f(x,y) :=
   \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{if} \ x\geq0, \ x\leq y \leq 1+x,\\
     -1 &\text{if} \ x\geq0, \ 1+x\leq y \leq 2+x, \\
    0 &\text{else}.
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Calculate 
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} \bigg(\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)\text{d}\lambda_1(y)\bigg)\text{d}\lambda_1(x) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \int_\mathbb{R} \bigg(\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y)\text{d}\lambda_1(x)\bigg)\text{d}\lambda_1(y).
\end{equation}

Comment: You have to show us your efforts, what where your attempts at calculating the integral, where you are stuck

Comment: Hint: Plot the regions where $f$ takes each value. Then $\int f(x,y)dx$ should be obvious and $\int f(x,y)dy$ easy.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that my problems are with the second integral. For the first integral I get 0(correct me, if i'm wrong). I tried the second integral in the same way like the first one by determining an interval in which my x has to be but by only adjusting the inequalities i didn't get something useful.

Comment: What can you say about $\int_0^x f(x,y)fy$ for $x\ge 2?$